How do you understand Auster's Baumgartner ending?
Paul Auster's last novel ends with a cryptic:
"When he comes to the first house and knocks on the door, the final chapter in the saga of S.T. Baumgartner begins."
My interpretation, which is pretty mundane, is that the author finished his book pointing to the possibility of a sequel, the so-called "final chapter in the saga", and indirectly encouraging himself to go on living and writing. Any thoughts?

Cryptically? I don't know that one can say for sure. Could just be irony.
